# Navigation to screen b in compose from splash screen

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a router which consist of two screens A and B. As soon as the user opens the app splash screen is shown. Now after that i navigates the user to screen B using navcontroller.navigate(screenBDestination). Now if i press back button i want to go on the screen A

Now what i want to do is, from the splash screen i want to add the screenA in navigation graph in background without navigating to it and directly navigate to screenB from splash, so now whenever i will press back button from screen B i will always be navigated to screenA.

So is there is any way to achieve this behaviour. I am using jetpack compose and navigation